# Exchange Web Service Error: Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: t:MimeContent

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I have got following error while loading `Itemproperty` set in EWS Please help

```
    EmailMessage foundEmail = (EmailMessage)item;
     PropertySet itemPorpertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties,
                       EmailMessageSchema.MimeContent,EmailMessageSchema.UniqueBody);
     itemPorpertySet.RequestedBodyType = BodyType.HTML;
        foundEmail.Load(itemPorpertySet);


Error:
     at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
           at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
           at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowUnclosedElements()
           at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
           at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
           at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
           at System.Xml.XmlCharCheckingReader.Read()
           at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadString()
           at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MimeContent.ReadTextValueFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader)
           at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ComplexProperty.InternalLoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader, XmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String xmlElementName, Func`2 readAction)
           at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ComplexProperty.LoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader, XmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String xmlElementName)
           at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ComplexProperty.LoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader, String xmlElementName)
           at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ComplexPropertyDefinitionBase.InternalLoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader, PropertyBag propertyBag)
           at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ComplexPropertyDefinitionBase.LoadPropertyValueFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader, PropertyBag propertyBag)
           at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertyBag.LoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader, Boolean clear, PropertySet requestedPropertySet, Boolean onlySummaryPropertiesRequested)
           at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsServiceXmlReader.ReadServiceObjectsCollectionFromXml[TServiceObject](XmlNamespace collectionXmlNamespace, String collectionXmlElementName, GetObjectInstanceDelegate`1 getObjectInstanceDelegate, Boolean clearPropertyBag, PropertySet requestedPropertySet, Boolean summaryPropertiesOnly)
           at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.GetItemResponse.ReadElementsFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader)
           at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.LoadFromXml(EwsServiceXmlReader reader, String xmlElementName)
           at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.ParseResponse(EwsServiceXmlReader reader)
           at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(EwsServiceXmlReader ewsXmlReader)
           at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.ReadResponseXml(Stream responseStream)
           at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(IEwsHttpWebResponse response)
           at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
           at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalLoadPropertiesForItems(IEnumerable`1 items, PropertySet propertySet, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
           at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalLoad(PropertySet propertySet)
           at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceObject.Load(PropertySet propertySet)
```

Answer (score 0):

The managed API object is failing to parse the response. So either the response is bad, or you've got an old version of the API. You might try getting the latest version of the API (either from [GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/), or from [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices/)). Or you could [enable tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn495632(v=exchg.150).aspx) and examine the response from the server to see if there's some problem there.